# Ajax form submit, can't figure out why it doesn't work

Tags: html, ajax, forms, serialization, submit

Does anyone have an idea why this does not work? The only data this serializes is the data from page 1. I also tried to have two different functions linked to each of the pages (and I had it as 2 separate forms, allthough then it will only overwrite eachother (and everything else).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
   $("#page3").text($("#q").serialize());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">
   <form id="q">
    <div data-role="content">
     <input type="checkbox" name="4[]" value="1">1</input><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="4[]" value="2">2</input><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="4[]" value="3">3</input><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="4[]" value="4">4</input><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="asdf[]" value="1">1</input><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="asdf[]" value="2">2</input><br/>
    </div>
    <a data-role="button" href="#page2">Next</a>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="content">
   <input type="checkbox" name="3[]" value="11">11</input><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="3[]" value="21">21</input><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="adf[]" value="1">11</input><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="adf[]" value="2">12</input><br/>
  </div>
 </form>
 <a data-role="button" type="submit" href="#page3" id="submit">Next</a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
</div>
```

Comment: I think form tag has to be  placed (open and closed) correct in document hierarchy.

Comment: Perhaps it would work with the form outside <div id="page1"> and <div id="page2"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem likely has something to do with how you have your first form interleaved with the outer divs - not permitted in HTML, not sure what the browser will make of this.  Can you close your first form within the div, start a new form inside the page 2 div?

Comment: I can, allthough I can't seem to get the information from both of them at the same time, perhaps it works if I send it to a .php script that can store it into my session as $_SESSION[question][answer] or something like that (which is the goal anyway), just having a hard time wrapping my head around all this information. Like how to "unserialize" etc. But the best thing would be to submit the whole form (divided into pages) at once, no way around this?

Comment: Not supposed to be that link in the middle. Supposed to be like $_SESSION[$question][$answer]

Answer (score 0):

its because all the checkboxs is not checked
, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mtde3/)

Comment: I've tried checking all/half/none, the only difference here is that I have my poll split into two "pages", and without any onClick functions. Point is to collect data and pass it on to a .php script that will insert the data into a MySQL database, just hard when I can't submit it all at once.

Comment: are you using jquerymobile to separate between page?

Comment: Yes, could that cause problems?

Comment: hmmm i think you should serialize per page, declare one global var, everytime you change page, you serialize current page, and store/concate it in  the global var

Comment: I am trying to make 1 ajax function that can be used for every page. Then fetch that data and store it into my session via php.